# Bitwise mask does not contain flag

Tags: bitwise-operators, bitmask

I want to check if a mask does not contain a flag. I've been writing it like this:

```
!(mask & flag)
```

But sometimes, the code gets a bit messy with all the parentheses. Is there a better way to write this? Something more concise?

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: JavaScript. But it would be nice to know if there were a general solution, if there is one.

Comment: That's how I'd write it. What do you mean "all the parentheses"? You have one pair of them. That's the smallest possible number of parentheses that isn't zero.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit too obsessive. I thought you might be able to write it like `(mask^flag)&flag` or `~mask | ~flag`, but they aren't any better.

Comment: (mask & flag) == 0 can sometime be clearer, but with the same parentheses number.